# DLLImport fails to find the DLL file

Tags: c#, dllimport

I have a C# application which needs to import a function from a C++ dll. I use DLLImport to load the function. It works fine in English and Chinese environment, but it always raise 'Module not found' exception in French operating system.

The code snapshot:

```
[DllImport("abcdef.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern string Version();
```

Note that letters in the name of module have been replaced but the name itself is in the same format and the same length.

And a screenshot:
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Got any code to show? What's the name of the module?

Comment: Here is the code. I replaced the alphabetic letters in the name but the same length. [DllImport("abcdef.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern string Version();

Comment: Are any of the replaced letters in the name "special" as in possible different depending on environment? Just grasping straws as I can't see any problem with the call.

Comment: No. All six letters are common ones.

Comment: Are there any other differences apart from language? Maybe 32-bit vs 64-bit? Is the imported DLL part of your application? If it's a system DLL can you show the real name you are using?

Comment: Fresh installed operating systems on both test machines and all are 32bit. The DLL file is a part of my application. Please have a look at the attached screenshot in the post.

Comment: Thanks for screenshot - does `sample.dll` have dependencies on VC++ runtimes? If so, maybe that's the problem. Check that you installed the relevant VC Runtime redistributables on the failing system.

Comment: yes, it depends on VC++ runtime. But, it still doesn't work with VC++ redistributable installed.

Comment: Try putting the dll and it's dependencies in the same directory as the app. What's in the Fusion Log?

Comment: Thanks all for your tips. I have tried Preet's method, not work again. What do you mean by Fusion log? I looked at Windows Log, there's no usefull message.

Comment: Just as a debugging step, I would run [Dependancy Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) on the different versions and see if that helps you find the misbehaving DLL that `sample.dll` depends on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried all methods you proposed, however the problem still exists.

Here is an alternative way which could avoid that error. It uses Win32 APIs to load the library and find the address of the function, then invoke it. Demo code follows:

```
class Caller
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private extern static IntPtr LoadLibrary(String path);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private extern static IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr lib, String funcName);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private extern static bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr lib);

    private IntPtr _hModule;

    public Caller(string dllFile)
    {
        _hModule = LoadLibrary(dllFile);
    }

    ~Caller()
    {
        FreeLibrary(_hModule);
    }

    delegate string VersionFun();

    int main()
    {
        Caller caller = new Caller("abcdef.dll");
        IntPtr hFun = GetProcAddress(_hModule, "Version");
        VersionFun fun = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(hFun, typeof(VersionFun)) as VersionFun;
        Console.WriteLine(fun());

        return 0;
    }
}
```